# bx slider with div background image issue

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a background image but for some reason I can't see it as I have given 100% height to make it responsive.

```
<ul id="slider">
    <li id="first"><div style="background-image: url(http://bxslider.com/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg); height:100%"></div></li>
    <li id="second">ddddd</li>
    <li id="third">ffff</li>
</ul>
```

JSfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/squidraj/7cEqM/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your `div` element has a height of zero, because it is empty. Therefore, you don't see it. You need to set its height in pixels or other units (em, rem).

Comment: The problem is if I set the height then the bx slider takes the height of 100% and creates a mess.I will try to post another fiddle. Also just thinking if there is any substitute way instead using height 100%

Answer (score 0):

if you have not special requirement to set image in background then use it in img tag then you dont need to do anything else.

```
make structure like this

<ul>
    <li><img src="path"/></li>
    <li><img src="path"/></li>
    <li><img src="path"/></li>
    <li><img src="path"/></li>
</u>
```